# Is there such a thing as .charAt().contains()?

Tags: java

Is there a way to compare a single char in a string to another string?  Here is an example:

```
String a = "0123456789";
String b = "5 + 3 / 2";

if(b.charAt(0) == 'something in string a') {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
b.charAt(i).contains(a)
```

Comment: `charAt()` returns a single character at particular index. Why would it have `contains()` method?

Comment: `isContainedIn` may make more sense, though even if `char` had methods it wouldn't be the normal way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(a.indexOf(b.charAt(0)) != -1){
   //There's a match
}
```

Comment: perfect,  thank a lot.  Can't believe I didn't think of indexOf.  I knew there was a way just could think of it.

Comment: @Greg  - Unless somebody specifically says how they voted, it's impossible to tell since voting is anonymous

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the opposite - rather than checking if "b is in a", check if "a contains b".

[`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) won't quite work in this situation, but 
you can do `a.indexOf(b.charAt(0)) != -1`

Comment: `contains` takes a char sequence rather than a char - that first option doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to find out whether the first character of `b` is one of those in `a` then you can do it this way:

```
if (a.indexOf(b.charAt(0)) != -1) ...
```

In other words, search the string for the character rather than trying to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`if("something in string a".contains(b.charAt(0)))` ---> do something

Comment: contains needs a char sequence rather than a char.

Answer (score 0):

1) `.contains()` is a String class method, hence cannot be used for primitive data type char
2) you can compare to chars just like integers b.charAt(i) == c.charAt(j), but cannot compare char to String